# Create folder loop function doesn't work

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sh, functions

I have created a function in a **.sh** file that creates directories in a loop with 3 parameters int: `start`, `end` and folder name `name`

But I am getting the following error:

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Here's function code:

```
#!/bin/bash
function createDirs () {
  start =  "$1";
  end =  "$2";
  name =  "$3";
  for i in {start..end}; do
    mkdir name"$i"
  done
}

createDirs "@"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply use

```
mkdir name{1..2}
```

instead of your script/function.

The command above will create two folders

```
name1
name2
```

---

Alternatively - a corrected version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function createDirs () {
  start="$1";
  end="$2";
  name="$3";
  for ((i=start; i<end; i++)); do
    mkdir "$name$i"
  done
}

createDirs "$@"
```

Comment: Thank you. Just curios why there are double bracers on the `for` loop?

Comment: Bash syntax. Not more not less ;)